# Keyerror on pd.merge()

Tags: pandas, merge, keyerror

I am trying to merge 2 data-frames ('credit' and 'info') on the column 'id'.

My code for this is:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM "credit"')
credit=c.fetchall()
credit=pd.DataFrame(credit)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM "info"')
info=c.fetchall()
movies_df=pd.DataFrame(info)
movies_df_merge=pd.merge(credit, movies_df, on='id')
```

Both of the id column types from the tables ('credit' and 'info') integers, but I am unsure of why I keep getting a key error on 'id'.

I have also tried:

```
movies_df_merge=movies_df.merge(credit, on='id')
```

Comment: What is the full key error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way how you read both DataFrames is not relevant here.

Just print both DataFrames (if the number of records is big, it will
be enough to *print(head(df))*).

Then look at them. Especially check whether both DataFrames contains
*id* column. Maybe one of them is *ID*, whereas another is *id*?
The upper / lower case of names does matter here.

Check also that *id* column in both DataFrames is a "normal" column
(not a part of the index).